# Can I get row_number to continue the sequence on a later query

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012, row-number

I've got the following query to give me a ROW_NUMBER that acts as a 'stage' in a case being progressed. This query runs under an INSERT INTO to populate a table.
At the minute we're having to re-build the table in full every month to capture every change in stage with a sequential row number (one row per stage of the case as the process moves on). The table will get too big to do this with at some point, I'd like to be able to append but the problem is, I can't think of a way to get the row numbers to continue from where they left off. I tried it in a test table and when I ran the query twice, doing November 2015 in two halves, any stages within each case that changed from the first half of November into the second half had the row number starting again from 1 if it was in the second run, instead of carrying on.

The column ModifiedRecordID is what identifies the cases and you can see is what the PARTITION BY is grouped on.

Is there any way to do what I'm thinking of?

```
SELECT  agc.ObjectTypeCode
   , ev.Name                           AS EntityName
   , agc.AttributeId
   , ea.AttributeName
   , ind.createdbyname                 AS CaseCreatedBy
   , agc.CallingUserName
   , agc.CallingUserId
   , LEFT(CAST(agc.OldFieldValue AS NVARCHAR(MAX)), ISNULL(NULLIF(CHARINDEX(',', CAST(agc.OldFieldValue AS NVARCHAR(MAX))) -1, -1), '')) AS ChangedField
   , UPPER(RIGHT(CAST(agc.OldFieldValue AS NVARCHAR(MAX)), LEN(CAST(agc.OldFieldValue AS NVARCHAR(MAX))) - CHARINDEX(',', CAST(agc.OldFieldValue AS NVARCHAR(MAX))))) AS PreviousGuidValue
   , wkt.ptl_name                      AS WorkType
   , ModifiedRecordId
   , ind.ticketnumber                  AS CaseRef
   , agc.ActionId
   , ind.createdon                     AS MatterCreated    
   , agc.LogDateTime                   AS AuditedDate
   , agc.AuditId
   , ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY ModifiedRecordId ORDER BY agc.LogDateTime ASC) Stage

FROM AuditGuidChange agc LEFT JOIN EntityView ev
                   ON agc.ObjectTypeCode = ev.ObjectTypeCode
                 LEFT JOIN EntityAttribute ea
                   ON agc.AttributeId = ea.ColumnNumber
                     AND agc.ObjectTypeCode = ea.MappedObjectCode
                 LEFT JOIN Peppermint_Data.dbo.incident ind
                   ON agc.modifiedrecordid = ind.incidentid
                 LEFT JOIN Filteredptl_worktype wkt
                   ON agc.PreviousGuidValue = wkt.ptl_worktypeid
WHERE LEFT(CAST(agc.OldFieldValue AS NVARCHAR(MAX)), ISNULL(NULLIF(CHARINDEX(',', CAST(agc.OldFieldValue AS NVARCHAR(MAX))) -1, -1), '')) = 'ptl_worktype'
AND CAST(agc.LogDateTime AS DATE) BETWEEN @sDate AND @eDate;
```

Comment: Not sure if I'm picturing your goal correctly, but maybe you can add the new row numbers to a subquery that gets the MAX existing row number for that partition?

Comment: Have you considered adding an [identity](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms186775.aspx) column to AuditGuidChange?  This would generate a unique, consistent, repeatable number for you?  Apologies if I've misunderstood the requirement, which I think *might* be the case.

Answer (score 1):

```
declare @offset int = 12;
select id, ROW_NUMBER() over (order by id) + @offset  as rn 
from table;
```